# Getting null pointer exception in Singly linked list implemented class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to search for a customer by using these two methods below but i am getting this error while doing so
The customer with id 20131111 is not in the list and I just want it to return null to the console

```
public  Customer search(int id){
        int year = idToYear(id);
        SLLC listOfCustomers = (SLLC) tree.search(year);
         Customer x = listOfCustomers.getCust(id);
        //if (listOfCustomers == null) return null;

        //for (int i=1; i<listOfCustomers.size()+1; i++){
        //  Customer searchedCustomer = listOfCustomers.get(i);
            //if (searchedCustomer.getId() == id){
                //return searchedCustomer;
            //}
        //}
        

        return x;
    }
```

```
public Customer getCust(int id) {
        
        Node temp = head; 
        if(temp.equals(null) ) {
            return null; 
        }
        else
        {
            while(temp != null) {
                if(temp.data.getId() == id) {

                    break; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    temp = temp.next;
                }

            }

            return temp.data; 
        }
    }
```

This is in the test class at line 71 I know error occurrig because the cutomer with this ID is not in the list but how to I make this just return null

```
 System.out.println(gym.search(20131111));
```

the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GYM.search(GYM.java:30)
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:71)
```

Comment: The problem isn't in `TestClass`, it's `GYM.java` line 30.

Comment: Thank you @AndyTurner, I swiftly fixed it after seeing you comment 
just added at try and catch block at line 30 in GYM.java 
Thanks !

Comment: A try/catch block is rarely the correct fix for a NPE. Work out what inside the try causes the NPE, and check for null before that executes.

Comment: okay, I will take a look 
thanks